Switch back from Smarty3 to Smarty2 - CiviCRM 5.71.1
Is there a way to switch back from Smarty3 to Smarty2
CiviCRM 5.71.1 + WordPress

Remove the line of the code 'CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH ' in civicrm.settings.php
